# finding rows of an array that all columns has inf value

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that some rows have `inf` value,but I need to find rows that all columns have `inf` value. I can find one row with `inf` value but I need that all values of this row be `inf`. my array is `nxm` and all `m` column should have `inf` to be selected. do you know how can I do this in python?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change equality if need all rows with "inf", written this way for better understanding**

What you need to do find the **minimum** value in each row & check if that is not 'inf' than that row is eligible for output. Below is the example code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf],[5,7,6,9],[1, 2, np.inf, 4]])
a[a.min(axis=1) != np.inf]
```

Output will be :
array([[ 5.,  7.,  6.,  9.],
[ 1.,  2., inf,  4.]])

Updating as per the OP question in comments - how to get row index of filtered row

```
np.where([a.min(axis=1) != np.inf])[1]
```

The output of this will be **array([1, 2])**, rows with atleast one non 'inf' value (in above example 2 & 3rd row, index 1 & 2).

Similarly

```
np.where([a.min(axis=1) == np.inf])[1]
```

This will return **array([0])** , index of row (in above example case, 0th row) with all the 'inf' values.

Comment: Thank you. is it a way to have the index of rows too? I need to know which rows will be removed.

Comment: I need to save these rows in another array for further computing.

Comment: but cant you directly save these row like new_array = a[a.min(axis=1) != np.inf] or new_array = a[a.min(axis=1) == np.inf] based on need.

Comment: this means I can not have the index of removed rows? I have to test other solution?

Comment: I have updated above code to get the index of filtered rows, hope this answers the question.